# Flutter web Http post request not working using http package

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-http

Making http post request fails on flutter web. I am using http package for making request here is my code:

```
http.post(
      'http://x.x.x.x:5000',
      headers: <String, String>{
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":
            'true', // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
            "Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, OPTIONS"
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'title': 'title',
      }),
    )
```

> Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 906:28                get current
> packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 84:22                                       
> dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1450:54                                              runUnary
> dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 143:18                                        handleValue
> dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 696:44                                        handleValueCallback

Note: In chrome Dev tools I can see 2 requests going through one is my post request and I don't know about the other one. The other one is always successful with 200 status and is logged at server but that isn't my post request.

Answer (score 2):

After wasting hours looking for a solution I have found that I haven't implemented CORS on server side. I was using Flask server and adding CORS quickly resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a server-side issue.

Enable CORS in Cpanel to enable CORS in your hosting account. you can enable it by adding the following lines in the **.htaccess file** in your hosting account.

<IfModule mod_headers. ...
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"